# How to set revolution anchor when using b2RevoluteJointDef

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

The demo program is once slide the screen. The body (In my case, it is a blue cannon) will rotate correspondingly. So I defined a revolution joint for the cannon body and ground body, but seems the anchor is not setting correctly and lead to can't rotate the body with mouse joint. "international practices"，I would upload related coding/screen next. Please see if you can help me.

Picture 1: Define related body,revolution joint

Picture 2: Touch callback function:Create mouse joint

Picture 3: Simulator screen(From the simulator,Seems the revolution anchor point is not correct)

**I can't upload image or post img links here due to lack of "reputation", I have added the img links in myself comment .**

Comment: Pic 1:http://i.imgur.com/OYrqY.png Pic 2:http://i.imgur.com/EzseG.png Pic 3:http://i.imgur.com/CfDHN.png

Comment: Do you see the mouse joint being drawn when you swipe on the screen? Is it in the right place?

Comment: When i wipe the screen,The cannon body would flash for a while,Is that count?

Comment: Sorry, I just remembered that mouse joints don't get drawn by the debug draw anyway. I wonder if the ground body and the cannon body are colliding... can you turn the cannon by another means, eg. ApplyTorque or ApplyAngularImpulse? You can set collideConnected to false for the revolute joint to make sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, when creating revolute joint you should use Initialize, like this:

```
cannonJointDef.Initialize(groundBody, cannonBody, cannonBody->GetPosition());
```

Last argument is anchor point in the world coordinates. In this case it will be the center of the cannon.

Then, try to rotate cannon without mouseJoint, just by setting rotation directly:

```
CGPoint touchVec = ccpSub(touchPos, _cannon.position);
float angle = ccpToAngle(touchVec) - M_PI_2;
cannonBody->SetTransform(cannonBody->GetPosition(), angle);
```

Comment: I don't think it is because of i didn't use  the initialization method,At first,I initialize revolute joint with "cannonJointDef.Initialize(groundBody, cannonBody, cannonBody->GetPosition());" ,But it didn't work too.   OK,I will try "SetTransform()" But why can't use mouse joint?

Comment: I run this on another MAC yesterday,It can run correct,I don't know if it is as original PC's problem.Anyway,It solved now.Thanks your guys